# Azure DevOps Pipeline Hosted Agent - where to find system capabilities?

Tags: azure, msbuild, azure-devops

Where can I see the system capabilities of hosted agents? I went here and it only shows user capabilities:

https://dev.azure.com/{myOrg}/{myProj}/_settings/agentqueues?agentId=8&queueId=91&view=capabilities

Trying to find versions of msbuild and paths to it on the computer. I need to use version 16

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the tools and softwares installed on the Microsoft hosted agent [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops#use-a-microsoft-hosted-agent). Click the **Link** shown as below screenshot to see the included softwares.

[image]

Unfortunately msbuild seems not installed separately, as it cannot be found in above hosted agents. But you can directly use [Msbuild task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/msbuild?view=azure-devops) and specify the msbuildVersion to 16.0 in your pipeline. The pipeline will automatically download the specified version msbuild from the cloud.

And also you can build your own [self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops) to run your pipeline. and manually download msbuild version 16 to your on-premise machine. So that you can specify the msbuild location in msbuild task to your on-premise msbuild location.
[image]

Comment: thank you, but I call msbuild from a powershell script so i need the exact path. is there just a way to download it?  similar to the nuget tool installer?  if so how would I get the path?  I would rather not use self-hosted.

Comment: If you check the task log of the Msbuild task, You will see the msbuild.exe location from its execution command. For agent windows-2019. it is located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\msbuild.exe`

Answer (score 1):

They have actually open sourced the Hosted Agents and you can find out all the information required from the repositories:
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/blob/master/docs/pipelines/agents/hosted.md

The have links for each of the Images that are available at this link:
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/blob/master/docs/pipelines/agents/hosted.md#software

***Windows2019-Agent***
https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/master/images/win/Windows2019-Readme.md

You can also add Demands to Agents:
[image: Azure DevOps Demands]
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/demands?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml
This can be used to ensure the agent has your the specific software needed for your builds.

Comment: thanks but I am unable to find the place to make demands.  seems azure web site is different than the documentation... can't put screenshots here so i go into agent pools, click "Azure Pipelines" or "Default" - it has 4 tabs at top "Jobs", "Agents", "Details", Security".  I click on Agents.  It only has "Hosted Agent". i click on that.  there are only 2 tabs at top "Jobs" and "Capabilities" and I'm back to screenshot in my original post.  what am i missing? thanks

Comment: Looks like you have already marked an answer, but for Demans, you need to go into the pipeline / release you are configuring. Select "Agent Job 1" or whatever you have labled the "Run on Agent" button. There you will see the Demands option once you have configured all the required fields. @dan

Comment: Lachie, thank you, i see that, if I add a demand then it doesn't have a list of software to choose from, it is a textbox we have to enter.  I can't find documentation on how to make sure MSBuild v16 is installed, can you provide any more direction? thanks